# Java HW, Printing out a multidimensional array of Ints, with Strings/characters

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, n-queens

I did an N queens java project that required me to print out a multidimensional array showing where I can place the queens. My array is of Ints. It prints out 1s and 0s in respectable positions. I was wondering if there was a way that I could print out a Q for queens in the place of a 1 and a space in the place of a 0, without changing my array to type String. I went back and changed my array to String type and I got nulls in the place of some 0's.

I tried converting the int to is ASCII character (81 would be a Q).

I also tried copying the Int array into a String array, but java doesnt allow that. Any Ideas?

```
    public void print(){

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{

    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j]==1){

            a[i][j]=((char)81);

        }
        System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        if(j < a[i].length - 1) System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

```
Solution :
0 0 0 0 0 81 0 0
81 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 81 0
0 0 0 81 0 0 0 0
0 81 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 81 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 81
0 0 81 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Try `System.out.print((char)a[i][j]);`

Comment: thanks, that partly worked for me. I got Qs when I changed the [i] to 81. The [j] just shows an empty space, maybe I make a grid with |, or --- to make it look more like a table.

Comment: Yes now you can do it as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{

    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
    {
        if (a[i][j]==1){

            System.out.print("Q");
            if(j < a[i].length - 1) System.out.print(" ");

        } else{
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
            if(j < a[i].length - 1) System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Unless you need a "Q" stored in the array, can't you just print the "Q" out when needed...then it will show up in the results as you want.

Comment: Cool, if you this was helpful, consider accepting my answer for my time!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.out.print((char)a[i][j]);
```

instead of

```
System.out.print(a[i][j]);
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, `1` will not evaluate to `Q` when casted to a `char`.

Comment: Yes but OP has changed it to 81.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
   {            
      if (a[i][j]==1){
           System.out.print('Q');
      }else{
           System.out.print(" ");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this prints out Qs but on one line

Comment: it would help to provide commentary to your answer explaining it